# Virtual Inheritance - base shared with other derived classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

Bjarne Stroustrup writes:

> When defining the functions for a class with a virtual base, the programmer in general cannot know whether the base will be shared with other derived classes.  This can be a problem when implementing a service that requires a base class function to be called exactly once.

I don't understand this statement.
What possible problems can creep in?

To explain it he gives strange example

```
class A {                             // no constructor
    // ...
};
class B {
  public:
    B();                              // default constructor
    // ...
};
class C {
  public:
    C(int);                           // no default constructor
};
class D: virtual public A, virtual public B, virtual public C
{
    D() { /*... */ }                  // error: no default constructor for C
    D(int i) : C(i i) { /*... */ };   // ok
    // ...
};
```

Is it relevant here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine you have a virtual base class that needs to be initialized by calling `.initialize(42)`, exactly once. The point is, you don't which derived class should call it.

```
struct X : virtual A {
  X() { 
     // here 
  }
};

struct Y : virtual A {
  Y() { 
     // or here 
  }
};

struct Z : X, Y {
  // what about this    
};
```

The correct answer in this case is "sometimes here, sometimes there", but you don't know which is the case (depends on which class is the most derived subobject).

C++ solves this issue for constructors, st. the constructors for all virtual bases are called exactly once in the most derived subobject's constructor; any constructor in the hierarchy must be prepared to call the virtual base constructor (although at runtime, it might not happen).

Comment: :please explain this line in above statement " the programmer in general cannot know whether the base will be shared with other derived classes."this line is killing me .which base is he refering??

Comment: can you provide an another example(other than constructor) where base class function has to be called only once

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a situation like this:

```
struct Base
{
    Base() { }
    virtual void call_me();
};

struct A : virtual Base { A() { call_me(); } };
struct B : virtual Base { B() { call_me(); } };

struct Derived : A, B
{
    Derived()
    :  Base()       // virtual base is construced in most-derived
    ,  A()
    ,  B()
    {  }
};
```

Now the warning is about the fact that the intermediate classes `A` and `B` may possibly assume that they are the only ones which call `Base::call_me()`. If their inheritance of `Base` were non-virtual, that would indeed be the case, as both `A` and `B` would have their own, unique base class. However, with virtual inheritance, it is *not up to* `A` and `B` to determine who ends up as their base class, as only the final class `Derived` installs the actual, single base class that is shared by all the intermediaries. Thus in our example, *both* `A` and `B` end up calling `call_me()` on the *same* base object.

The moral is that operations that pertain to a virtual base class should be the responsibility of the *most derived* class. Since that is not a rigid concept, and inheritance can practically be extended indefinitely, this is a slippery slope. Virtual, multiple inheritance is a complex concept.

Comment: In your ex:- you haven't override callme().But you begin calling it in class A and class B.second I think call_me() will be called twice first by A(),then by B().Also please explain this line-" the programmer in general cannot know whether the base will be shared with other derived classes." it is killing me

Comment: @10001001058: The author of `A` may never know that *someone else* is deriving from it as well as from other classes that derive from `Base` virtually, so `A` may not assume that it is the only one calling `Base::call_me`.

Comment: i think call_me will we executed twice in your code on same object .But problem is something different. isn't.It is to implement Base class function only once which are defined in A and B